# Highlighting elements is not working in selenium java using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, salesforce-lightning

This below code is not working in Salesforce lightning page for highlighting the web element. But, it is working fine in normal web page and Salesforce classic page.

```
public static void highLightElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.background='green'", element);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(700);
}
```

While using this code the script is not failing. But it is not highlighting the element